# slider revolution: slider inside slider

Tags: jquery, wordpress, plugins, revolution-slider

I'm using WordPress and I have revolution slider, layer slider and Js Composer plugins installed.
I want to create a slider which will contain sliders. Which means nested slider or slider of sliders or whatever its called.
I need to build like this page's pick your interest part.
http://www.biznessapps.com/mobile-smb-apps.php

I've tried with revolution slider and visual composer also, but couldn't find anything like this.

Please suggest me which way is good for this. I can do hardcode by myself. But it may not be a good solution for WordPress I think.

Comment: It is not a slider, it is internal linking and scroll effect.

Comment: Is it jquery tab based? Should I create it using jquery tabs and inserting single sliders inside each tab?

Comment: Example Tutorial: http://designshack.net/?p=20323 you can google for many such.

Comment: Or is there any plugin which is best suited to accomplish this? please suggest. Thanks

Comment: I'm looking into your recommended tutorial. But is there any possibility to create it using js-composer/visual composer plugin?

Comment: to be honest, no idea.